# Storing file in lists uses 10x memory as file size

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have an ASCII file that is essentially a grid of 16-bit signed integers; the file size on disk is approximately 300MB. I do not need to read the file into memory, but do need to store its contents as a single container (of containers), so for initial testing on memory use I tried `list` and `tuples` as inner containers with the outer container always as a `list` via list comprehension:

```
with open(file, 'r') as f:
    for _ in range(6):
        t = next(f) # skipping some header lines
    # Method 1
    grid = [line.strip().split() for line in f] # produces a 3.3GB container
    # Method 2 (on another run)
    grid = [tuple(line.strip().split()) for line in f] # produces a 3.7GB container
```

After discussing use of the grid amongst the team, I need to keep it as a list of lists up until a certain point at which time I will then convert it to a list of tuples for program execution.

What I am curious about is how a 300MB file can have its lines stored in a container of containers and have its overall size be 10x the original raw file size. Does each container really occupy that much memory space for holding a single line each?

Comment: show the code for how you calculate the size of `grid`

Comment: It's strange that those two would give different sizes, because they are the exact same code. You have to call `tuple(foo_list)` to make it a tuple.

Comment: `[(line.strip().split()) for line in f]` is the __exact__ same thing as `[line.strip().split() for line in f]`, so I wonder how you calculate `grid` size to get different sizes. And actually, if you really have both statements in that order, the second will produce an empty list since `f` has been exhausted by the first one.

Comment: Maybe [this helps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/519633/lazy-method-for-reading-big-file-in-python#519653).

Comment: In the file, each character costs you one byte. Every python string object has an additional overhead of around 50 bytes: `sys.getsizeof('') -> 49`, `sys.getsizeof('a') -> 50`. That's 50 extra bytes for every cell in your grid. If your average token has a length of `5`, there's your factor `10`.

Comment: @Chris_Rands Thanks, I just thought a second time and came to the same conclusion ;)

Comment: @Chris_Rands No code for that, just native OS support. No other applications running, run a python program and monitory process in Task Manager (goes from 25K to 3.7Million K).

Comment: @AaronKlein Made a typo (copy past was not available). I do call `tuple(foo_list)` to build a list of tuples, I don't just surround in `()`.

Comment: @rocksteady Doesn't solve the problem. I need to store the content, and reading is not an issue since I never read the file into memory plus build a container from it.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers Made a typo, it isn't just `(foo_list)` its `tuple(foo_list)`. Also, I don't execute them as shown for the reason you stated, just showing which methods I had applied to test.

Comment: @schwobaseggl Each cell in the grid ranges from 0 to -9999 (lots of the -9999), so that means the `'-'` gets 50 bytes and each `'9'` gets 50 bytes. Why does python give so many bytes for a string??

Comment: @schwobaseggl A quick brain-lapse reminded me these are 16-bit ints so I changed the grid to `[list(map(int, line.strip().split())) for line in f]` and reduced memory footprint by 1.2GB.

Comment: @pstatix No, every token has `1` byte for each character + `~50` bytes overhead for the str object (can be different depending on your system and python version): so '-9999` needs `49 + 5 = 54` bytes. Casting to int certainly saves some memory. An `int` needs ~28 bytes

Comment: @schwobaseggl Okay, tracking now; still, why the additional ~50? If the string could occupy 5 bytes, why not leave it?

Comment: @pstatix these are the inner workings of the C implementation. See e.g. [this blog](https://www.laurentluce.com/posts/python-string-objects-implementation/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are concerned about storing data in memory and do not want to use tools outside of the standard library, you might want to take a look at the `array` module. It is designed to store numbers very efficiently in memory, and the `array.array` class accept various type codes based on the characteristics of the numbers you want stored. The following is a simple demonstration of how you might want to adapt the module for your use:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3
import array
import io
import pprint
import sys

CONTENT = '''\
Header 1
Header 2
Header 3
Header 4
Header 5
Header 6
 0 1 2 3 4 -5 -6 -7 -8 -9 
 -9 -8 -7 -6 -5 4 3 2 1 0 '''


def main():
    with io.StringIO(CONTENT) as file:
        for _ in range(6):
            next(file)
        grid = tuple(array.array('h', map(int, line.split())) for line in file)
    print('Grid takes up', get_size_of_grid(grid), 'bytes of memory.')
    pprint.pprint(grid)


def get_size_of_grid(grid):
    return sys.getsizeof(grid) + sum(map(sys.getsizeof, grid))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: How have I never heard of the `array` lib? Does an `array.array` support indexing and assignment? The grid is 2D, so I may need to access `grid[13][25]` for a value.

Comment: @pstatix Yes, you can get items out of an array and set item in an array via indexing.

Comment: Why call `tuple()` on the array instantiation? Do you have to convert it to a `tuple` or `list`?

Comment: @pstatix If you are concerned about memory usage, compare the results from the following two statements: (1) `sys.getsizeof(tuple(None for _ in range(10 ** 6)))` and (2) `sys.getsizeof(list(None for _ in range(10 ** 6)))` For each million rows, 244 KB extra is used for a list. If `array` instances do not need to be replaced in the grid, you are better off with using a `tuple`.

Comment: Just ran this solution, 3.3GB down to 194MB. How, how, how have I never heard about `array`?? Documentation is seriously limited though, only discussing member functions of the array class, only a single line mentioning ['Arrays are sequence types and behave very much like lists...'](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/array.html#module-array). The slice operator even works wonderfully!